# Combining GeoServer vector tiles with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, vector-tiles

I am using QGIS 3.8 (or 3.4) with the vector tile plugin:
https://github.com/geometalab/Vector-Tiles-Reader-QGIS-Plugin
I've also installed the vector tiles plugin for GeoServer 2.15.1.

The problem that I am facing is how to integrate these 2 plugins. The tutorial on GeoServer handles how to integrate OpenLayers with Vector tiles.

But the QGIS plugin requests a:

- TileJSON url
- and/or a GL Style JSON url

I cannot find in the GeoServer documentation anything about what these URL's might be.

[image: Interface]

I've tried a couple of urls based on what I see Openlayers is doing, but no progress.

Does anyone have an idea of how to make this work?

EDIT: added extra picture for Dror:
[image: xtr]

EDIT 2: 
I did more investigating, I think the QGIS plugin needs a capabilities document specifically looking like: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a tilejson that's a spec by mapbox and you can build GL JSON style sheet with resources like sprites,glyps and fonts.Thats what QGIS requires. Open layers has a extension/plugin for GL JSON styling for vector tiles. You can use several open source tools for building style sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have defined your service to output vector tiles the url for the tiles should be something like this:

```
http://pcpb620:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=belmap:buildings&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}
```

This type of URL should work in OpenLayers as well.

### EDIT

It seems geoserver doesnt support outputing tilejson.
As @GeospatialInformationTech stated the implementations of tilejson are listed [here](https://github.com/mapbox/tilejson-spec/wiki/Implementations).

You can however connect regular WFS, WMS and WMTS services from GeoServer to QGIS, for a WMTS source you can use a url like:

```
http://pcpb620:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=belmap:buildings&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326&FORMAT=image/png&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This is indeed what I'm expecting for the actual request of the tiles. But the interface for the vector tile plugin seems to expect a sort of get capabilities (I'll add an overview of the interface in the description). I've tried adding the http://pcpb620:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0 in the url screens, but to no avail. The url itself does work and does show <Format>application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile</Format>